# htaccess redirect to homepage with bad url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this redirect htaccess code to change the file.php to /file/ so the URLS are more SEO friendly.

```
RewriteEngine On

# hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

However, when someone types in a bad url like - domain.com/file/whateverblablabla-wrong

I am getting an Internal Server Error.

I would like it to redirect to the homepage or if I choose a specific URL for a 404 page so I can have a sitemap or something maybe..

Much thanks,
-O

Comment: That internal error is not being generated from these rules. Check your Apache error.log to see what is the actual error.

Comment: Not sure if this is it: [Thu Aug 07 08:48:19 2014] [error] [client 24.186.15.215] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On

# hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

This will disable any previously set `ErrorDocument` directives.

Comment: nope still getting error... see this url and just add jibberish to end of url - www fusionwireless com

Comment: I just tried `http://www.fusionwireless.com/123456` and got standard 404 error. So no 500 error. You should test this in a new browser.

Comment: sorry, try going to a page first.. in the nav.. and then type jibberish u get a different error.. i know odd right... i would also like it to redirect at least to the homepage...

Comment: I just did that and clicked on few links. Finally when I tried `http://www.fusionwireless.com/careers1111` I got 404 again.

Comment: Yes, no more server error.. but it still goes to NOT FOUND... i would like it to go back to homepage or even to a specific page like 404.php with a sitemap - is that possible?

Comment: yes see updated code, it will goto `/404.php` now. Make sure you have `/404.php` under root.

Comment: Fantastic that worked! Thank you much better .htaccess file now. However one more glitch - on wireless-products/ a link takes you to /rate-plans/#pre-paid to jump to a section on rate-plans/ but its messed up it should be /rate-plans.php#pre-paid - bc of the htaccess now its not working

Comment: I don't see any rule here that is adding `#` in the URL. Looks like you have some code issues. Make sure in your code you use absolute links, one that start with `/` or `http://`

Comment: I double - check it works... thanks for your help master